# Kubernetes - How to run local image of jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have config file like this :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenkins
        image: aaa-aaa/jenkins.war.LTS.2.89.4
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
          - name: jenkins-home
            mountPath: jenkins_home
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          emptyDir: {}
```

I have in same directory of this config file, an image of jenkins : `jenkins.war.LTS.2.89.4`

How can I deploy with using this image ?

Comment: You have a docker image of Jenkins in a local registry?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu it's warfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not run a war file of Jenkins directly on kubernetes. You need to create a docker image of that war file to be able to run it on kubernetes.

Follow this [guide](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/10/16/custom-war-packager/) to create a docker image of the war file.

Once you have a docker image you can push that image to a remote or local and private or public docker registry and refer that url in the kubernetes deployment yaml in `image` section.

Also I would suggest to use [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins) of Jenkins to deploy Jenkins on kubernetes.